# MySQL Performance: NOT NULL UNIQUE constraint on natural keys vs separate natural key => surrogate key mappings (tables)

Tags: mysql, database-design

Here is a small design with the common NOT NULL UNIQUE constraints on the natural keys:

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' {
    id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    pass NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id')
}
```

The NOT NULL UNIQUE constraint seems hackish to me. Having disjoint candidate keys seems denormalized to me, and the UNIQUE constraint seems like a bloated O(N) checking feature, so I'm inclined to use a design that has a relation for each natural key that maps the natural key to the surrogate key in the main relation.

```
CREATE TABLE users {
    id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pass NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id')
}
CREATE TABLE user_names {
    name NOT NULL,
    user_id NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('name')
}
CREATE TABLE user_emails {
    email NOT NULL,
    user_id NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('email')
}
```

This way, I implicitly enforce the unique constraint on user's emails and usernames while providing the luxury of being able to search for a user's info with their email or name in O(ln N + ln M) time (which I very much desire).

This only way I can ever see the first, more common design matching the performance of the second design is if the UNIQUE constraint implicitly indexed the table so that selects with, and therefore checks for uniqueness of, the natural keys can be done in O(ln N) time.

I suppose my question is, with regard to the performance insertions and selections with the natural keys, what is the best way to handle a table with 3 or more natural keys that is indexed by a surrogate key?

Comment: In your second schema one user (users.id) can have many names and emails. In the first one, only one. And as @dportas mentioned, in the first schema name and emails are enforced NOT NULL, in the second that can be NULL  -- well, missing. Not sure that comparing these two schemas on performance makes much sense.

Comment: "Having disjoint candidate keys seems denormalized to me" Unlike many elements of design, normalization is based on formal logic, so it's a matter of fact, not a matter of opinion. Having multiple candidate keys violates no rule of normalization until you get to 6NF. (And that's a rare state, in my experience.) I suggest you  study normalization until having multiple candidate keys seems more normal. (cough)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are describing is [6th Normal Form](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/CS253/CS253-Temporal-Data.pdf). Assuming your original table is in 5NF then your new schema consisting of 3 tables is in 6NF. Having three candidate keys does not violate 5NF but it would violate 6NF.

From the data integrity point of view however 6NF has significant disadvantages. It is normally the case that some dependencies are lost. For example your original table enforces the constraint that every user has a name and password. Your 6NF version can't do that - at least not in SQL if you want to permit inserts to all the tables. 6NF is useful for some specific situations (temporal data) but in general 5NF is more useful and desirable from a data integrity perspective.

This doesn't answer your performance question but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: I agree but I will add that performance will be hurt since doing joins DOES have costs and I think is rather obvious if you think that now you have to do 3 inserts instead of 1 based on what Mitchell describes.

Comment: I appreciate the input. @Icarus: But certain searches are faster

Comment: @Mitchell, since the two schemas are logically so very different I'm not sure it's sensible to compare them on performance alone. They do not model the same set of requirements so you are not comparing like for like.

Comment: @dportas: Right, I realize that now thanks to your answer. I'm obviously concerned with optimizing the performance of the first scheme. Is it sensible to index the natural keys within the table alongside the primary key index, essentially creating multiple primary keys?

Comment: @Mitchell. Yes. Multiple keys make perfect sense if they accurately model the business domain and usually it makes sense to index a key. Most SQL DBMSs require indexes for key enforcement.

Answer (score 0):

You are **normalizing** too much in my opinion. You will hurt performance not only on inserts/updates but also on selects since you are now joining 3 tables instead of doing a straight insert/select/update/delete in one table.

I disagree that the NOT NULL UNIQUE is hackish but I do find strange that there's such a constraint on a name column.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't consider looking up name/email based on id. Also, name/pass are meant to be login credentials.

Comment: @Mitchel in that case, please consider renaming the name column to "username" in the Users table you described first because it gets confusing to see a name column with a unique constraint.

Comment: @Icarus, This is an example of *normalization*, not *de*normalization.

Comment: @dportas Sorry, you are correct. NORMALIZATION, I meant. Thanks, I will correct my statement.